# How to submit the n-th form in iMacros for Firefox

Tags: html, forms, imacros

Using `iMacros` want to submit the n-th (e.g. the third) `form` on a website.

However there is no `ID` and no `name` tag. All the examples i have found use `ATTR`, `ID` or `NAME`.

e.g. `TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:idadsf ATTR=ID:id234324`

How can I submit such a `form`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to update this question with the answer:
Any field can be set to wildcard *, so in our case where we want to submit the 3rd form we set POS=3 and set the required ATTR to VALUE:*

```
TAG POS=3 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=VALUE:*
```